# Custom ChoiceField in Serialiers - Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have an issue hope you guys help me. I want to have a ChoiceField with user field which `choices=` User who is participants and have last_name is 'Z'.

My serializer:

```
class ArticleCreateSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    user_choice = SerializerMethodField()
    user = ChoiceField(choices=user_choice)
    class Meta:
        model = Feed
        fields = [
            'id',
            'user',
            'post',
            'participants'
        ]
   def get_user_choice(self, obj):
        user_choice = User.objects.filter(id=obj.participants, last_name='Z')
        return user_choice
```

**Error:**

```
TypeError: 'SerializerMethodField' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
class ArticleCreateSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    def get_user_choice():
        user_choice = User.objects.filter(id=obj.participants, last_name='Z').values_list('username',flat=True)
        return user_choice

    user = ChoiceField(choices=get_user_choice())
    class Meta:
        model = Feed
        fields = [
            'id',
            'user',
            'post',
            'participants'
        ]
```

Comment: `TypeError: get_user_choice() takes exactly 2 arguments (0 given)`

Comment: I updated the answer... Removed the parameters of  `get_user_choice()`

Comment: Please review. If removing params `(obj, self)`, cant user `obj.participants` after that!